# Set Discord Bot Activity to the number of Online users. Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want the bots status to show the amount of people that currently are online. I have been trying with this code but it keeps saying:

*TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function*

```
//Checks if the bot is online
client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);

  //Activity
  var guild = client.guilds.get('id here');
  var onlineCount = guild.membersCount.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
    client.user.setActivity('games with ' + onlineCount + ' people' , { type: 'PLAYING' });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you now need to use the `cache` property to access `guilds` collection, so you need to replace `var guild = client.guilds.get('id here');` with `var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('id here');`

---

**Unrelated to the question**:
You are getting the `guild`'s [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) and filtering it to get the number of online users in that guild, the problem with that is that `memberCount` returns a `number` not a collection of [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)s, what you need to use is the [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) property instead, which to access that collection, you need to use `cache` again:

```js
var onlineCount = guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size
```

Comment: If I would want to also filter idle and dnd. Would that be possible in the same line?

Comment: `filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online' || m.presence.status === 'dnd' || m.presence.status === 'idle')`

Comment: I just realised I could also do !== 'offline' which would yield the same results xD