# How to get and display the number of online participants on the site (JS)?

Tags: javascript, web, discord

How can I use JS to get the number of online participants in a particular Discord server and display this number on the site?

I tried this construction, but I always got 404:

`

```
let discordStatusID = (id here);
$.ajax({
   url: "https://discord.com/api/memberCount/" + discordStatusID + "/embed.json",
   success: function (data) {
      let presence_count = data.presence_count;
      updateDiscordStatus(presence_count);
   },
   error: function () {},
   timeout: 300000,
});

function updateDiscordStatus(presence_count) {
   let discordStatusDiv = $(".discord-status");
   discordStatusDiv.empty();
   if ((presence_count > 1) || (presence_count < 1)) {
      discordStatusDiv.html("<span class='status-number'>" + presence_count + "</span> " + users_online);
   } else {
      discordStatusDiv.html("<span class='status-number'>" + presence_count + "</span> " + user_online);
   }
}
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Discord Bot Activity to the number of Online users. Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61566398/set-discord-bot-activity-to-the-number-of-online-users-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

- **First, we create a new channel in our server. Text or speech can be used, although most people prefer voice because it looks more like an announcement.**
- **The next step is to create the counters folder and the
  member-counter.js and members-online.js files within it.**
- **Next, we'll call the functions to count each necessary variable from index.js.**
- **Then we'll perform a count using the timeout technique after a predetermined interval, renaming the channel with the updated result.**

Below is a demonstration that will help you achieve the outcome you want.
I've added a members count as well so you have both ready to use.

*Run..*

- **npm init**
- **npm install discord.js**

*if necessary.*

**index.js**

```
    const Discord = require("discord.js");
    const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: 32767 });
    const memberCounter = require("./counters/member-counter");
    const membersOnline = require("./counters/members-online");
    
    client.on("ready", () => {
      memberCounter(client);
      membersOnline(client);
    });
    
    client.login(
      "YOUR_TOKEN_HERE"
    );
```

**member-counter.js**

```
    module.exports = async (client) => {
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID HERE"); //guild id where you want to show the member count
      setInterval(() => {
        const memberCount = guild.memberCount; //get the member count from the guild
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL 1 ID HERE"); //channel id to be renamed every 60 seconds
        channel.setName(`Total Members: ${memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
      }, 60000);
    };
```

**members-online.js**

```
    module.exports = async (client) => {
      const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("GUILD ID HERE"); //guild id where you want to show the members online
      setInterval(() => {
        // Get the total number of Users Online, idle and with the do not disturb status
        const countUsersOnline = guild.members.cache.filter(
          (m) => m.presence?.status === "online"
        ).size;
        const countUsersIdle = guild.members.cache.filter(
          (m) => m.presence?.status === "idle"
        ).size;
        const countUsersDnD = guild.members.cache.filter(
          (m) => m.presence?.status === "dnd"
        ).size;
    
        const membersOnline = countUsersOnline + countUsersIdle + countUsersDnD; //Add members together (online, idle, dnd)
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL 2 ID HERE"); //channel id to be renamed every 60 seconds with the total number of members online
        channel.setName(`Members Online: ${membersOnline.toLocaleString()}`);
      }, 60000);
    };
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't apply this method to the site, since I need to output data to the site, then if I connect a file with a token to the site, security will collapse. The token will simply be stolen and will gain access to the technologies that work in Discord.

I need a method how I can (for example, through parsing) get the number of participants by ID and display on the website. The same wget will download all JS files, even if they are not connected.